# Update data Axios - Put method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a question on the HTTP put method using Axios.  I'm creating a task scheduling application utilizing React, and Express with a MySQL database. I want to be able to update task data.  So far, I have my project opening a modal on the specific task with an edit button being clicked. I have a get request populating form with the existing data. It is not passing Task ID # from the ExpressJS route /tasks/update/:TASK_ID. I tried passing the ID as a parameter to the update button click-event handler.  It is undefined. I know the problem is related to Axios put data request and not being passed an ID. I want a put request working. Ideas? Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

```js
/* ExpressJS DB API - server.js */

const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
var path = require('path');





const app = express();


  
const updateTasks = 'UPDATE TASKS SET TASK_NAME=?, TASK_DESC=?, TASK_LOCATION=?, ASSIGNED_TO=? WHERE TASK_ID=?';

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'mysql',
   user: 'root',
   password: 'passwd',
   database: 'task_db',
   port: 3306    
});

conn.connect(error => {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(`Connected!`);
});

console.log(conn);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('css'))
app.use(express.static('js'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public','css', 'js')));





/* Look here! */
app.put('/tasks/update/:TASK_ID', (request, response) => {
    
const TASK_NAME = request.body.Name;    
const TASK_DESC = request.body.Desc;
const TASK_LOCATION = request.body.Location;
const ASSIGNED_TO = request.body.Assign;    
const id  = request.params.TASK_ID;    
    
    conn.query(updateTasks, [TASK_NAME, TASK_DESC, TASK_LOCATION, ASSIGNED_TO, id], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        return response.send(error);
      }


      else {
        response.send(JSON.stringify(results));
        }
      

    });    
    

});

app.use(function (request, response) {
  response.status(404).send("400 Not Found! Page does not exist...");
});

app.use(function (request, response, error) {
  console.log(error.stack);
  response.status(500).send("500 Something is broken!");
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
   console.log(`Tasks server listening on port 4000`)
});
```

```js
/* App.js file */

import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import Overview from './Overview.js';



class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      tasks: [],
      Name: '',
      Desc: '',
      Location: '',       
      Assign: '',
      taskUpdate: false,
      modalIsOpen: false,          
  };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleTaskEdit = this.handleTaskEdit.bind(this);
    this.handleTaskUpdate = this.handleTaskUpdate.bind(this);
//    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getTaskData();
}
    
    
getTaskData = () => {
    
fetch('http://localhost:4000/tasks', {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({ tasks: response.data }))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
}   

  handleChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
  

/* Look here! */  
handleTaskEdit = (TASK_ID) => {
/* https://github.com/PerfectTechCoding/crudapp-react
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRm35KtMZzw
*/
            fetch("http://localhost:4000/tasks/" + TASK_ID, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},    
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                    modalIsOpen: true,
                    taskUpdate: true,
                    Name: response[0].TASK_NAME,
                    Desc: response[0].TASK_DESC,
                    Location: response[0].TASK_LOCATION,
                    Assign: response[0].ASSIGNED_TO 
                });
         
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log("Error", error));
    
}



closeModal() {
  this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
}

/* Look here! */
handleTaskUpdate = (event, TASK_ID) => {
        
    
//event.preventDefault();
       
    
let data = {
    Name: this.state.Name,
    Desc: this.state.Desc,
    Location: this.state.Location,
    Assign: this.state.Assign
};
    
//const { tasks } = this.state;    
    
    
axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/tasks/update/${TASK_ID}`,data)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
//    alert("New Task record updated successfully!");
//    window.location.reload();
})
   .then ((data) => {
  console.log(data);  
})    
   .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
})    
      
}


  

  

render() {
     
 const { tasks, Name, Desc, Location, Assign,  modalIsOpen  } = this.state;
 console.log(tasks);
 console.table(tasks);    

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
            



        <Route path='/overview' render={() => (
        <Overview tasks={tasks} delete={this.handleTaskDelete} change={this.handleChange} edit={this.handleTaskEdit} Name={Name} Desc={Desc} Location={Location} modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen} Assign={Assign} afterOpenModal={this.afterOpenModal} closeModal={this.closeModal} update={this.handleTaskUpdate}/>
        )}/>



      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

```js
/* Overview.js file */

import React from 'react';
import TaskBreadcrumb from './TaskBreadcrumb.js';
import AssignmentIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Assignment';
import DoneOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DoneOutline';
import NotificationsActiveIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NotificationsActive';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import {
  Helmet
} from "react-helmet";
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import SortableTable from 'react-sortable-table';

//import { SortIconBoth, SortIconDesc, SortIconAsc } from './Icons';
window.React = require('react');


class Overview extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: '',
        Taskcomplete: false
      };
      this.handleComplete = this.handleComplete.bind(this);
      this.handleTaskRemind = this.handleTaskRemind.bind(this);
      this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
    }


    handleCheck = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        Taskcomplete: !this.state.Taskcomplete
      })
    }

    ////openModal = (task) => {
    ////  this.setState({    
    ////    modalIsOpen: true,  
    ////    Name: task.TASK_NAME,
    ////    Desc: task.TASK_DESC,
    ////    Location: task.TASK_LOCATION,
    ////    Assign: task.ASSIGNED_TO  
    ////});
    ////}
    //
    //afterOpenModal() {
    ////  this.subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
    //}
    //
    //closeModal() {
    //  this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
    //}

    handleComplete = (event) => {
      console.log("Task Complete!")
      const complete = this.state.Taskcomplete;
      event.preventDefault();

      if (complete) {
        event.target.style.color = '#000';
        console.log("Task Incomplete!")
      } else {
        event.target.style.color = '#f00';
        this.setState({
          complete: true
        });
        console.log("Task Complete!")
      }

      console.log(event.target);
    }

    handleTaskRemind = () => {
      console.log("Task Reminder alert!")
    }



    render() {





      const customStyles = {
        content: {
          top: '50%',
          left: '50%',
          right: 'auto',
          bottom: '10%',
          marginRight: '-50%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
        }
      };

      const inputs = {
        width: "30%",
      };

      const labels = {
        fontWeight: "bolder",
      };

      const btnSubmit = {
        width: '33%',
        fontWeight: 'bolder'
      }

      const incomplStyle = {
        fontWeight: 'bolder',
        color: 'blue'
      };

      const complStyle = {
        fontWeight: 'bolder',
        textDecoration: 'underline',
        color: 'red'
      };

      const status = this.state.Taskcomplete ? 'Complete!' : 'Incomplete!';
      const statusStyle = this.state.Taskcomplete ? complStyle : incomplStyle;

      function getTaskName(TASK_NAME) {
        return TASK_NAME.split(' ').slice(-1)[0]
      }

      const TASK_NAME_Sorter = {
        desc: (data, key) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          var result = data.sort(function(_a, _b) {
            const a = getTaskName(_a[key]);
            const b = getTaskName(_b[key]);
            if (a <= b) {
              return 1;
            } else if (a > b) {
              return -1;
            }
          });
          return result;
        },
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        asc: (data, key) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line 
          return data.sort(function(_a, _b) {
            const a = getTaskName(_a[key]);
            const b = getTaskName(_b[key]);
            if (a >= b) {
              return 1;
            } else if (a < b) {
              return -1;
            }
          })
        }
      };

      const columns = [{
          header: 'Task ID',
          key: 'TASK_ID',
          defaultSorting: 'ASC',
          dataProps: {
            className: 'align-right'
          },
          render: (TASK_ID) => {
            return <a href = {
              'http://localhost:4000/tasks/' + TASK_ID
            } > {
              TASK_ID
            } < /a>; }
          },
          {
            header: 'Task Name',
            key: 'TASK_NAME',
            headerStyle: {
              fontSize: '15px'
            },
            headerProps: {
              className: 'align-left'
            },
            descSortFunction: TASK_NAME_Sorter.desc,
            ascSortFunction: TASK_NAME_Sorter.asc
          },
          {
            header: 'Task Description',
            key: 'TASK_DESC',
            headerStyle: {
              fontSize: '15px'
            },
            headerProps: {
              className: 'align-left'
            },
            descSortFunction: TASK_NAME_Sorter.desc,
            ascSortFunction: TASK_NAME_Sorter.asc
          },
          {
            header: 'Task Location',
            key: 'TASK_LOCATION',
            headerStyle: {
              fontSize: '15px'
            },
            headerProps: {
              className: 'align-left'
            },
            descSortFunction: TASK_NAME_Sorter.desc,
            ascSortFunction: TASK_NAME_Sorter.asc
          },
          {
            header: 'Status',
            key: 'TASK_ID',
            headerStyle: {
              fontSize: '15px'
            },
            sortable: false,
            render: (TASK_ID) => {
              return <div style = {
                statusStyle
              } > < div > {
                status
              } < /div><input type="hidden" name="Taskcomplete" checked={this.state.Taskcomplete} onChange={this.handleCheck} id={TASK_ID} aria-label="Task complete"/ > < /div>; }
            },
            {
              header: 'Person responsible',
              key: 'ASSIGNED_TO',
              headerStyle: {
                fontSize: '15px'
              },
              headerProps: {
                className: 'align-left'
              },
              descSortFunction: TASK_NAME_Sorter.desc,
              ascSortFunction: TASK_NAME_Sorter.asc
            },
            {
              header: 'Actions',
              key: 'TASK_ID',
              headerStyle: {
                fontSize: '15px'
              },
              sortable: false,
              render: (TASK_ID) => {
                return <div > < button id = {
                  TASK_ID
                }
                className = "w3-button"
                title = "Edit Task"
                onClick = {
                  () => this.props.edit(TASK_ID)
                } > < EditIcon / > < /button> <
                button id = {
                  TASK_ID
                }
                className = "w3-button"
                title = "Delete Task"
                onClick = {
                  (event) => {
                    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this task?')) this.props.delete(TASK_ID)
                  }
                } > < DeleteIcon / > < /button> <
                button id = {
                  TASK_ID
                }
                className = "w3-button"
                title = "Task complete"
                onClick = {
                  this.handleComplete
                } > < DoneOutlineIcon / > < /button> <
                button id = {
                  TASK_ID
                }
                className = "w3-button"
                title = "Task reminder"
                onClick = {
                  this.handleTaskRemind
                } > < NotificationsActiveIcon / > < /button></div > ;
              }
            }
          ];

          const style = {
            //      backgroundColor: '#eee'
          };

          Modal.setAppElement('#root')


          const iconStyle = {
            color: '#aaa',
            paddingLeft: '5px',
            paddingRight: '5px'
          };

          return (

              <
              div className = "w3-container" >
              <
              Helmet >
              <
              title > Reroot Task Scheduler - Task Overview < /title> < /
              Helmet > <
              TaskBreadcrumb / >
              <
              div className = "w3-card-4" >
              <
              div className = "w3-container w3-green" >
              <
              h1 className = "w3-animate-top" > < AssignmentIcon / > Task Overview: < /h1> {
              //        <EditModal/>
            } <
            /div> <
          div className = "w3-responsive w3-margin-bottom" >
          <
          SortableTable data = {
            this.props.tasks
          }
          columns = {
            columns
          }
          style = {
            style
          }
          iconStyle = {
            iconStyle
          }
          /> < /
          div > <
          /div>

          <
          Modal isOpen = {
            this.props.modalIsOpen
          }
          onAfterOpen = {
            this.props.afterOpenModal
          }
          onRequestClose = {
            this.props.closeModal
          }
          style = {
            customStyles
          }
          closeTimeoutMS = {
            3
          }
          contentLabel = "Edit Task Modal" >
          <
          button onClick = {
            this.props.closeModal
          }
          className = "w3-button w3-circle w3-right" > < CloseIcon / > < /button> <
          div className = "w3-card-4" >
          <
          div className = "w3-container w3-green" >
          <
          h2 className = "w3-animate-top w3-center" > < EditIcon / > Modify Task: < /h2> < /
          div >

          <
          form className = "w3-container w3-margin-bottom" >

          <
          p className = "w3-left-align" > < label htmlFor = "taskName"
          className = "w3-text-purple"
          style = {
            labels
          } > Task Name: < /label> <
          input type = "text"
          name = "Name"
          className = "w3-input w3-border w3-round w3-light-grey w3-wide w3-animate-input"
          onChange = {
            this.props.change
          }
          id = "taskName"
          style = {
            inputs
          }
          value = {
            this.props.Name
          }
          placeholder = "Enter a task name"
          autoFocus required / > < /p>

          <
          p className = "w3-left-align" > < label htmlFor = "taskDesc"
          className = "w3-text-purple"
          style = {
            labels
          } > Task Description: < /label> <br/ >
            <
            textarea id = "taskDesc"
          name = "Desc"
          rows = "10"
          cols = "50"
          className = "w3-border w3-round w3-light-grey w3-wide"
          placeholder = "Enter a task Description"
          onChange = {
            this.props.change
          }
          value = {
            this.props.Desc
          }
          required > < /textarea> < /
          p >

          <
          p className = "w3-left-align" >
          <
          label htmlFor = "taskLocate"
          className = "w3-text-purple"
          style = {
            labels
          } > Task Location: < /label>  <br/ >
            <
            select name = "Location"
          id = "taskLocate"
          className = "w3-border w3-wide w3-round w3-light-grey"
          onChange = {
            this.props.change
          }
          value = {
            this.props.Location
          }
          required >
          <
          option value = "" > Select Task Location < /option> <
          option value = "Reroot Pontiac HQ" > Reroot Pontiac Headquarters < /option> <
          option value = "Reroot Sustainability Center" > Sustainability Center < /option> <
          option value = "Some place" > Some place < /option> <
          option value = "Other place" > Other place < /option> <
          option value = "Etc." > Etc. < /option> < /
          select > <
          /p>

          <
          p className = "w3-left-align" >
          <
          label htmlFor = "taskAssign"
          className = "w3-text-purple"
          style = {
            labels
          } > Task Assigned to: < /label>  <br/ >
            <
            input type = "text"
          name = "Assign"
          className = "w3-input w3-border w3-round w3-light-grey w3-wide w3-animate-input"
          onChange = {
            this.props.change
          }
          id = "taskAssign"
          style = {
            inputs
          }
          value = {
            this.props.Assign
          }
          placeholder = "Enter a task name"
          required / >
          <
          /p>

          <
          p className = "w3-center" >
          <
          button type = "submit"
          onClick = {
            this.props.update
          }
          style = {
            btnSubmit
          }
          className = "w3-button w3-cyan w3-round" > Update < /button> < /
          p > <
          /form>         < /
          div >

          <
          /Modal>


          <
          /div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Overview;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Evan! I'd be happy to help but there is wayyy too much irrelevant code. Please isolate the core of the issue and only leave the bits pertaining to the problem. Consider this a basic preparation work before asking any question. This will also make your question more likely to be answered. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more information.

Comment: You need to include a configuration option to the axios put request. Something like `const config ={headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"}}` if you are not accessing private routes in the backend that require a token. I'm not sure if this is the problem, but this is missing.

Comment: Hello!  I have updated it. Tried to add config with headers and still did not work. Any more ideas would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @EvanH. I think you need to do a little debugging, can you try testing your API by using POSTMAN or if it doesn't need auth token then you can simply test in chrome. If it works fine then there might be bug in frontend application. If it doesn't then there might be issue on your backend side

Comment: @VarunArya.  I've been doing that from the start.  Backend DB API works great and flawlessly.  I think, it is something related to my http put request and not being able to receive a Task ID #. Put in comments for where to look.  Any ideas? Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through your code, I found the issue due to which you're not able to TASK_ID to Http put method. You've not passed the required arguments to event handler.

Here is your method which handles onClick event when user tries to Update by clicking on Update button present in `Overview.js`

```
handleTaskUpdate = (event, TASK_ID) => {
  //rest of your code     
}
```

Here is your code accessing handleTaskUpdate method in `Overview.js`

```
<p className="w3-center">
  <button 
    type="submit" 
    onClick={this.props.update} //handleTaskUpdate passed as property named update
    style={btnSubmit}
    className = "w3-button w3-cyan w3-round" 
    >
     Update 
   </button>
 </p>
```

As you can see your method requires two parameters first one is synthetic event and second one is additional argument TASK_ID.

Currently you're not sending the additional argument "TASK_ID" to handleTaskUpdate method due to which TASK_ID will be `undefined`

Correct way of sending additional parameters can be done by various method (Below are few examples).

1. Using arrow keyword (Not preferred as you are essentially creating a new function that calls this.handleTaskUpdate method during each render)

   ```
   <button onClick={(event) => this.handleTaskUpdate(event, TASK_ID)}>Update</button>
   ```
2. Using bind keyword

   ```
   <button onClick={this.handleTaskUpdate.bind(this,TASK_ID)}>Update</button>
   ```
3. Using dynamic binding with the Arrow Function for multiple elements (I prefer this method)

   ```
   //using double bind method
   handleTaskUpdate = (TASK_ID) => (event) => {
     //rest of your code
   }

   //using handleTaskUpdate
   <button onClick={this.handleTaskUpdate(TASK_ID)}>Update</button>
   ```

Hope this helps in solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you @VarunArya! I am now getting a TASK ID #. Very close on this!  Only problem, getting SQL error 1048 stating values are NULL. Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: This happens when you have variable with undefined value and since the column doesn't accept NULL value. To debug this make sure you are sending valid values in request body in PUT request

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help! It works perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you upvote my answer and close the topic?